# Getting Meteor CFS:S3 working with Google interoperability

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

Has anyone got Meteor and CollectionFS:S3 working with Google's interoperability API? I have created keys and have used these in a standard S3 config with EU as region. There are no errors being presented in the app so this is a tricky one to debug.